# How to unit Test Angular 2 Mean Stack App?

Tags: mongodb, angular, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have created a mean stack application. With a user registration. Now i want to do some unit testings. Can anyone tell me how to do this with app. This app has been created using (Angular 2, Node, Express, MongoDB).

I have no idea about unit testings and how it should happen. Please explain me how to unit testings? What are the tools available?

Comment: The first Google result for "How to unit test Angular 2" is [Angular's own very good documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing) please do a bit of research before asking a question here

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/), how to do this is described well in [Angular's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing).

Comment: Does it test the backend of the application as well? sorry for asking silly questions. i have no idea about this :)

Comment: I don't really develop using express and mongodb, questions on stack overflow should really be limited to one specific programming question: you can read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. However I think the answer to what your asking could be found easily by just googling: How do I unit test  `example` for whatever you are looking to test